# Access violation at exit of the application

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2005

I have a access violation at the exit of my MFC based VS 2005 C++ application. It uses MFC as a shared library and multibyte char set options. The call stack reveals the functions like

```
CAfxStringMgr::Free(ATL::CStringData * pData=0x00e07c47)  Line 154 + 0x9 bytes  C++

__crtExitProcess
 doexit() 
exit() 
__tmainCRTStartup()
WinMainCRTStartup()
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the [ATL/MFC Trace Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241448%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure a version of it exists for VS 2K5.